# Running iconv.exe with vbscript in Windows

Tags: vbscript, parameters, arguments, iconv

When triyng to run iconv.exe under windows with the VBScript, the arguments don't go to executable.

```
Set SHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

SHL.Run """iconv.exe"" -f utf-16 -t utf-8 in.txt > out.txt"
```

I think it's error with quotes but can't find the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Run starts a process, not a shell. You need a shell for shell's features like re-direction. So:

```
Dim SHL  : Set SHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim iRet : iRet    = SHL.Run("%comspec% /c ""iconv.exe"" -f utf-16 -t utf-8 in.txt > out.txt", 0, True)
```